# How to solve Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs.net

I am getting the following error:

```
 Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment
```

InnerException:

```
Unable to resolve type: React.JavaScriptEngineFactory
```

InnerException:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

this is Application_Start

```
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

this is BundleConfig.RegisterBundles

```
   bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles").Include("~/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx"));
```

And this is Home/Index View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

    <script src="~/Scripts/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/react/react-dom.min.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles")
<div id="content"></div>
```

the error occurs at this line

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles")
```

**Update1**
When I tried to access /Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx directly in the browser I got this server error message:

```
MsieJavaScriptEngine.JsRuntimeException: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: it did not work .

Comment: find my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819464/reactjs-net-bundles-tinyiocresolutionexception-unable-to-resolve-type-reac/54171095#54171095

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS.NET - Bundles - TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.IReactEnvironment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819464/reactjs-net-bundles-tinyiocresolutionexception-unable-to-resolve-type-reac)

Answer (score 1):

We shoul create a static ReactConfig class and configure ReactSiteConfiguration with all the .jsx file present.

We should add our .jsx files to the scripts as follows

```
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
       public static void Configure()
       {
          ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
            .AddScript("~/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx");
       }
    }
```

In Application_start call

```
RouteConfig.Configure();
```

Comment: I added `ReactConfig` class as you suggest then I called `RouteConfig.Configure()` in `Application_Start()` but the error still exists

Comment: try calling @Html.ReactInitJavaScript() in the view below @script.Render

Comment: But, why the indirection? What purpose does it serve?