# Using BabelBundle on asp.net application, when using BundleResolver is not working

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bundling-and-minification, babeljs

In this moment I'm covert my *buddleconfig* to support babel transcription. For do that I have the following code:

```
bundles.Add(new BabelBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.HeaderApp).Include(
                "~/Scripts/MobileApp/Apps/HeaderApp.js",
                "~/Scripts/MobileApp/Controllers/HeaderCtrl.js"
            ));
```

Then, I what to get all scripts URL's in a List of string format as follows:

```
List<string> list =  new BundleResolver().GetBundleContents(virtualPath).ToList();
```

But the compiler retrives the following error:

> Unable to resolve type: React.IReactEnvironment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a search a lot and tried different solutions, the problem was that my project missed some libraries references.

Using the Nugget and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819464/reactjs-net-bundles-tinyiocresolutionexception-unable-to-resolve-type-reac) I was able to solve the problem